# MySQL 5.7 how to delete rows that have same values in one column but are not duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Here are my data:

```
CREATE TABLE cats
(
    cat_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    breed VARCHAR(20),
    age INT
);

INSERT INTO cats(name, breed, age)
VALUES
('otto', 'tabby', 10),
('jerry', 'mynx', 7),
('nina', 'stray', 7),
('gandolf', 'american shorthair', 13),
('dumbledore', 'wizard', 10);

mysql> select * from cats;
+--------+------------+--------------------+------+
| cat_id | name       | breed              | age  |
+--------+------------+--------------------+------+
|      1 | otto       | tabby              |   10 |
|      2 | jerry      | mynx               |    7 |
|      3 | nina       | stray              |    7 |
|      4 | gandolf    | american shorthair |   13 |
|      5 | dumbledore | wizard             |   10 |
+--------+------------+--------------------+------+
```

What I want to do is delete all the rows where the ages are the same in more than one row. In the example, after deletion, the only row I would have left is the row with cat_id = 4.

```
| cat_id | name    | breed              | age  |
+--------+---------+--------------------+------+
|      4 | gandolf | american shorthair |   13 |
+--------+---------+--------------------+------+
```

I have tried:

`DELETE FROM cats WHERE age IN (SELECT age FROM cats GROUP BY age HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)`

but that gives me an error: **ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'cats' for update in FROM clause**.

I've tried using a JOIN, too, but that ends up deleting all the rows.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I can do this in MySQL v 8.0 but I can't figure out how to do it in 5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql is a little fussy, try nesting your criteria in its own subquery:

```
 DELETE FROM cats 
 WHERE age IN (
  SELECT age FROM (
    SELECT age FROM cats 
    GROUP BY age 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )a
);
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fa9186b52629cc728b950d18ba1cf550)

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was missing in the subquery - add another subquery. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looking up this error i found [Yehor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1101589/yehor) answer, he provided a really good solution for the problem.

If you do this:

```
DELETE FROM cats 
WHERE age 
IN (SELECT age FROM cats GROUP BY age HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

you are going to get an error.

But if you wrap the condition in one more select:

```
DELETE FROM cats 
WHERE age IN (
  SELECT age FROM (
    SELECT age FROM cats GROUP BY age HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) AS a
)
```

You probably will receive this error:

`Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.`

Just disable safe mode and it would do the right thing!!

**Explanation**: The query optimizer does a [derived merge optimization](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/derived-table-merge-optimization/) for the first query (which causes it to fail with the error), but the second query doesn't qualify for the *derived merge optimization*. Hence the optimizer is forced to execute the subquery first.

Comment: Thank you, Guilherme. Your solution is the same as @Stu's, but I very much appreciate your taking time to provide input!

Comment: Nice expanded explanation for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, about 3 minutes after I posted this question, I figured out the answer. I was not using the right JOIN criteria.

Here is the solution I came up with - any critique is greatly appreciated!

```
DELETE c1 
FROM cats c1
JOIN cats c2
ON c1.age = c2.age
AND c1.name <> c2.name;
```

From the command line client:

```
mysql> DELETE c1
    -> FROM cats c1
    -> JOIN cats c2
    -> ON c1.age = c2.age
    -> AND c1.name <> c2.name;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from cats;
+--------+---------+--------------------+------+
| cat_id | name    | breed              | age  |
+--------+---------+--------------------+------+
|      4 | gandolf | american shorthair |   13 |
+--------+---------+--------------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```